# XAML GridView to GridView Drag and Drop Mouse vs Touch

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Here's XAML code where you can drag and drop GridView elements between different GridViews, however, this approach only works with mouse input and just partially with touch input.

With touch input the elements "unlock" from the GridView only on vertical drag. On horizontal drag the UI tries to scroll the screen instead of just moving the GridView element.

So mouse works perfectly and touch works only on inital vertical drag, after the inital vertical drag you can move the element around just as you could with mouse. This is a Windows 8 app.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate1">
            <Border Background="#25BDC0">
                <Grid Width="230" Height="230" Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridView Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate1}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FirstCollection}"
            AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" 
            DragItemsStarting="GridViewDragItemsStarting"
            Drop="GridViewDrop" Margin="10">
        </GridView>
        <GridView Grid.Column="1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate1}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SecondCollection}"
            AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" 
            DragItemsStarting="GridViewDragItemsStarting"
            Drop="GridViewDrop" Margin="10">
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled upon the same issue and found the answer here :

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7fcf8bb8-16e5-4be8-afd3-a21e565657d8/drag-and-drop-gridview-items-and-disabled-scrollbar

It appears that with a GridView you can't initiate the drag horizontally, you have to do it vertically and it's the exact opposite with the ListView.

So if you want to drag 'n drop items horizontally you have to use a ListView. (as recommended in the MS guidelines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465299.aspx )

Regards